# MySQL Workbench will not open on my Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have install **mysql-workbench** version 5.2.38+dfsg-3

via Ubuntu Software Center on my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop for some week ago,

This work fine until now!

Now when I press in the **mysql-workbench** icon in the Unity lanuncher,

It just start opening and then nothing happens :(

If I try start it via the terminal:
I get this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1004428/

**UPDATE:**

I can open it via: `sudo mysql-workbench`

But then is can save my passwords.. it says:

```
voidcode@voidcode-Aspire-5750:~$ sudo mysql-workbench
[sudo] password for voidcode: 
** Message: Gnome keyring daemon seems to not be available. Stored passwords will be lost once quit
Ready.
```

Comment: run it without <code>sudo</code> and with debug and verbose options, like this <code>mysql-workbench --log-level=debug3 --verbose</code>

Comment: I just get the same output as before: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1024423/

Comment: But I do not know what this log means... or what I can do to fix it ..